# Is EMV can be Cloned

Tags: clone, credit-card, emv

I see a lot of videos showing withdrawals from ATMs with cloned EMV cards like code 201 so
how can be possible when a card uses DDA (dynamic keys) another question is cloned card just for magstripe because it is unencrypted or even EMV chip

Answer (score 1):

It is a question that does not really belong to SO and due to the nature of what you are asking about, you may not receive a detailed answer. I will still try.

First of all, ATMs are online-only devices that do not need any form of Offline Data Authentication so DDA has little to do with them normally (there are exceptions from this rule, as usual).

There are still dynamic keys that are meant to provide security, nevertheless. A standard symmetric-key algorithm is used to generate online cryptogram and it is validated by the issuer. Symmetric keys are individual to each specific card and are not easily extracted (of course, nothing can be ever treated as 100% secure, but it would require a complex hardware attack to extract keys from a single card).

I assume your question about Service code 2xx, 5xx or 6xx is mostly revolving around magstripe data with no chip data available. In some situations (i.e. when card is mute) a fallback to magstripe transaction may happen. Normally, unattended devices should have this option blocked and decline such attempts but I would not bet there are no such devices around the world. You also need to consider that there are still devices that are not EMV-capable.

When it comes to magstripe data, they can be easily modified (for instance changing the service code) although such modification should be detectable. Same goes for using EMV track equivalent data on magstripe. In both cases, issuer is capable of detecting modification of the data or using it on different interface through the use of CVC/CVV which is encoded on a track and is created to cryptographically protect integrity of the track data. However, this requires to have proper implementation on the issuer side to detect and decline such attempts where cryptographic data from CVV or cryptogram are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I am being told that an atm withdrawal had my exact chip information.  I made a withdrawal at an atm in Florence , the atm took four tries, and at the same time another withdrawal was being made at atm 13 minutes away.  The technology must have advanced.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).